# Scrabble word finder in C#

Tags: c#, wordsearch

What I'm trying to do right now is take a user input, and check a text file to see if you can make any of the words in the text file out of the input entered.

For example, if I entered "noqmopu", the output would be:
moo
moon
mop
muon
pun
quo
upon

My code is below. I've omitted the rest of the program since it's finished and would use up space. What I've tried to do is, if the inputted string is larger than the word that is being checked in the text file, it'll convert both to a char then compare each letter of the input to the word. If the characters match, a counter adds 1 to itself and the for loop breaks to prevent a letter being matched twice. Then, if the counter is equal to the length of the word, that would mean you could make out the word from the inputted string and it gets printed on the screen.

At the moment, if I type "noqmopu", all that gets printed out is 'n' (which is one of the words in the text file). I realize I'll have to limit the printed words to words with 3 characters or higher, but I'd like to know how to resolve this first. If there's another way of doing this, that'd be great, but I'd also like to know why this isn't working. I can't use any Systems.Collections. Thanks.

Comment: where is the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping over the line twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
    {
```

I think one of those was supposed to be looping over the `input`

Comment: I think you're right. The first for should have had i < input2.Length. Now when I try this though, it prints a lot more words than it should; words that have letters that aren't even in the input. Guess I'm still missing something....

Comment: @Martyax whats an example of `line` and `input` that gives weird results. Your code is a little complicated for a simple task like you describe

Comment: Not sure you have fully accounted for repeat characters eg input "aaa" would match word "ant"

Comment: Well going with the input of "noqmopu" that I mentioned above, now I get bon
bop
con
cop
coup
don
fop
go
ho
Hom
hop
Io
ion
Juno
lo
lop
Lou
m
moan
mob
monk
moo
moon
morn
mot
moun
moun
mour
mow
n
nob
nod
non
nor
norm
not
noun
now
of
ohm
omen
one
onus
open
opiu
opt
opus
or
our
out
ow
own
ox
p
phon
pion
Po
pod
poem
poi
pol
pomp
pond
pong
pont
pony
pop
pot
poun
pour
pout
pow
pro
prom
pun
quod
romp
Ron
so
son
sop
sou
soup
ton
top
von
won
wop
yon
you

Comment: What value of `line` gives that result for `noqmopu` input?

Comment: 'line' gets the words from the text file from StreamReader myReader so I don't think it has a value really?

@Graham I'm not sure either haha

Comment: Looks like I got it! Along with the first for loop needing to be input2.Length, the case for repeat characters wasn't fully accounted either as mentioned. Adding a 'lineChar[j] == ' '; inside 'if(lineChar[j] == inputChar[i]) fixed the issue. Thanks!